# Connecting to Java process running as a Windows service: How does JProfiler does it?

Tags: windows, service, jvisualvm, jprofiler, jstat

How can I connect a trace tool like JvisualVM - not using JMX - to a Java process running as Windows service?

The JVM running as service is strted When i start JvisualVM, it does not 'see' the JVM running as service: there are some unanswered question regarding it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293335/windows-server-2008-and-jstatd-as-a-service) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031359/jvisualvm-doesnt-list-certain-java-processes). i found some useful tips [in this blog post](http://blogs.oracle.com/nbprofiler/entry/monitoring_java_processes_running_as), but they not always work.

Jprofiler has the magic button 'Show Services' which solves to problem: does anyone know how they do it? how can i do the same to connect using JvisualVM?